# Difference between libgdx and andengine

Tags: android

How to choose between libgdx and andengine?. Some people suggest using ligdx. Some others prefer andengine. If someone is favouring one above the other what would he consider choosing betweeen the two?

Comment: There's no such thing as "the best" for that matter. Asking for the differences is OK, asking for the best is unanswerable. You should rephrase your question a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a matter of preference.

On the one hand, Andengine is a lot more beginner friendly. 
On the other, libgdx is quite powerful and offers bindings for OpenGL 1.0, 1.1 and 2.0.

libgdx, while being really lightweight compared to Andengine, is also capable of delivering a fully 3D experience while Andengine caters for developers and game designers interested in it's 2D capabilities.

See here for a more thorough comparison:

http://www.dustypixels.com/2010/11/17/native-android-ogl-game-libraries-3-of-the-best/